# Windows 98 Lubuntu dual boot - Windows not booting

Tags: multi-boot, lubuntu, windows-98

I've got my hands on an Asus laptop, a l3000tp if I'm not mistaken (part of the l3tp family).

It has a Pentium 4 processor, 512 MB RAM and a 40 GB hard drive. 
I wanted to install Windows 98 on it for some good ol' games and Lubuntu 16.04 should I need to connect it to the Web without being part of a netbot.
Now, I've managed to install windows 98, then I proceeded to resize the HD and make space for Lubuntu; I did that before installing windows but windows took control of the whole disk, not just the partition I created for it.
Lubuntu installed successfully as well, and the GRUB recognized windows so I thought, job done!

Nope!

On selecting windows at boot it won't actually boot, all I have is a blank screen with a blinking cursor.  Lubuntu, on the other hand, boots fine.
I'm pretty sure it messed up when resizing the windows partition. 
Is there a way to recover windows and still have the dual boot? If not, what's the best way to have them on dual boot?

I really don't want to format again, but I'll do it if it's the only way. 
And just in case, I'm aware that I could just throw a virtual machine on Lubuntu and run Windows that way, but I have my good reasons for not doing it.

Comment: I wonder id windows 98 didn't take well to the resize. What's your partition layout look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the good answer from karel and the suggestions from other users, nothing has worked for **repairing** the existing Windows 98 installation. Nonetheless, I've managed to succesfully get the computer up and running again, with Lubuntu and Windows 98 in dual boot.

All I had to do was format the whole hard drive again with Windows FORMAT utility and, when prompted, tell it not to format in FAT32 the whole disk but just a portion of it (in my case 14 GB, which I'm aware is overkill, but who cares).
After that it's just a matter of installing Windows on the existing partition.

Only then, with Windows 98 installed, I can proceed to install Lubuntu as usual, taking care of installing it on the unformatted portion of the drive and without touching the Windows partition, not even for resizing it.
After Lubuntu installation, both OSs are booting and working normally.

Thank you to everyone that stopped by and helped me.

Answer (score 0):

## Boot Repair

From  Lubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install -y boot-repair
sudo boot-repair
```

Open the Boot Repair application and select *Advanced Options* -> *Other Options* tab -> *Repair Windows boot files*. The boot flag should be placed on the same partition on which Lubuntu is installed. The partition on which Lubuntu is installed can be identified from the Gnome disk utility (*gnome-disk-utility*) application which is built-in in Lubuntu.

[image]

If you're unable to select the *Repair Windows boot files* option because it's grayed out, refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947346/how-do-i-boot-windows-10-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-3/947628#947628).

## Rescatux

[Rescatux](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/) is a free bootable live CD/USB that can repair GRUB and the Windows bootloader. Rescatux has a graphical interface with a menu of operating system rescue tasks. If your hard disk has the MBR partitioning format, you can select the *Restore Windows MBR (BETA)* option to repair the Windows bootloader.

**Boot options:**

- (>=0.41 beta 1) Update UEFI order
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Create a new UEFI Boot entry
- (>=0.41 beta 1) UEFI Partition Status
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Fake Microsoft Windows UEFI
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Hide Microsoft Windows UEFI
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Reinstall Microsoft Windows EFI
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Check UEFI Boot

**GRUB options:**

- (>=0.40 beta 11) Easy GNU/Linux Boot Fix
- Restore GRUB and GRUB2
- (>=0.31 beta 4) Update any GRUB2 menu
- Update Debian/Ubuntu GRUB menus

**Windows options:**

- Restore Windows MBR (BETA)
- Clear Windows passwords
- (>=0.31 beta 4) Promote a Windows user to Administrator role
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Reinstall Microsoft Windows EFI
- (>=0.31 beta 4) Unlock Windows user

**Password options:**

- Change GNU/Linux Password
- Regenerate sudoers file
- Clear Windows passwords

[image]
<sup>**Rescapp is a nice wizard that will guide you through your rescue tasks.**</sup>

---

#### How to make a Rescatux live USB

Follow the instructions at [How to make a Rescatux USB](http://wiki.rescatux.org/wiki/Main_Page#How_to_make_a_Rescatux_USB).

To prevent overwriting a partition on your hard drive by accident and losing all the data on that partition, make sure you know which is your USB device before you write the Rescatux iso.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I'll give it a try tonight and let you know.

Comment: I've tried the boot repair option, but on selectin Windows 98 all I get is the message: "setting partition type to 0xc"
I'm scratching my head now...

Comment: That means it is looking for a UUID which doesn't exist. Use `sudo blkid` in the terminal to find the correct UUID for whichever partition it is referring to. That information will be in the Boot-Repair Boot Info Summary (the 3rd option in the first screenshot).

Comment: Well, it seems that both blkid and the boot repair summary point to the same UUID for the Windows partition. Am I missing something?

Comment: Here's the pastebin: https://pastebin.com/z8YmtATE

Comment: Seems normal. Did you assured Windows was booting after shrinking the partition? Grub can only boot working Windows.

Comment: @MichaelBay The Lubuntu installation shrunk the partition, so the answer is no, Windows wasn't working right after the partition resizing. It might be just easier reinstalling Windows 98 from scratch since there's nothing in there really. Is it possible without having to run the usual format C:?

Comment: That exactly why it's often recommended to shrink the partion in Windows, with Windows tool and do a `chkdsk` for good measure. Only after assuring Windows is happy with its new partition size should one proceed  to install the other OS. Now you need several steps:  1. Repair Windows (this will override Grub); 2. Boot a Ubuntu live session and reinstall Grub.

Comment: Does Windows 98 even have a partition resizing tool? Sorry, it's just been years I haven't used it

Comment: Small update: After wiping the whole disk, I've managed to format 14GB of it (out of 40GB total) in FAT32 with Windows 98 format tool, leaving the rest unformatted. I'll try tonight to install it on that partition and throwing Lubuntu on the empty one. Hopefully, it'll work. I'll keep this post updated.